# Long SE site names will break the top bar in the mobile layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, top-bar

As of the release of the new top bar on mobile (which is fantastic), any site with a sufficiently long name will completely break out of the top bar. The below problem occurs in the stock browser for Android, in which the screenshots are taken. My device is a HTC One running Android 4.3.

This is the current front page of [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) in mobile:

[image: the heading is popped out of place]

The same happens on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), or [Role-playing Games Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/), or any site with a sufficiently long name such that the title just doesn't fit into the space given to it.

It looks like this with the user bar expanded. Note the hovering magnifying glass and the white bar still being present:

[image: still out of place]

Comment: That ... should not be a thing. What browser/device are you using?

Comment: @AnnaLear This occurs in the stock Android browser. The screenshots were taken in Dolphin browser for Android.

Comment: @AnnaLear HTC One, Android 4.3

Comment: @AnnaLear I've updated this with a screenshot from the stock browser itself, to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Device sizes and pixel ratios are a lot of fun.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! It's working fine now.